# React input type number default value

Tags: reactjs, input, react-hooks, default-value

The current state is zero and it shows zero on the input, I want to change the input value to any other number? I didn't include the full code just where is having an issue. Thanks

```
 const [value, setValue] = useState(0)
<input type="number" value={value} min="0" onChange={handleOnChangeSoda} required/>
```

Comment: You need to post the code for `handleOnChangeSoda`.

Comment: `const handleOnChangeSoda = e => {
        setSoda(sodaPrice * [e.target.value])
        setValue(value)
    }`

Answer (score 2):

```
handleOnChangeSoda = (event) => {
  setValue(event.target.value)
}
```

the value set will be a string so if you want it to be a number do a ParseFloat or ParseInt on event.target.value

Answer (score 0):

const [value, setValue] = useState(0)
<input type="number" value={value} min="0" onChange={(val)=>setValue(val)} required/>

//i think this will work